# POST request using React with Hooks and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am making a React app where I need to add Redux using Hooks. Currently, I am stuck in making a POST request and can't figure out after going through the internet, how to make it work. I am on my way to understand how the Redux works and I will be happy for any help on this to make it work, so I can understand what is missing and how to send the data. My components:

**App.js:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import "./App.css";
import Posts from "./components/posts";
import { addPost } from "./store/actions/postAction";

function App() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [body, setBody] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const post = {
            title: title,
            body: body,
        }
        
        addPost(post);

        setTitle('');
        setBody('');

        alert("Post added!");
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Posts />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Mew post:
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="title"
                        placeholder="Add title"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="body"
                        placeholder="Add body"
                        value={body}
                        onChange={e => setBody(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect()(App);
```

**postAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_POSTS, ADD_POST, POSTS_ERROR } from "../types";

const url = "http://localhost:8002/";

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${url}posts`);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_POSTS,
            payload: response.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: POSTS_ERROR,
            payload: error,
        });
    }
};

export const addPost = (post) => (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = axios.post(`${url}`, {post});
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_POST,
            payload: response.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: POSTS_ERROR,
            payload: error,
        });
    }
};
```

**postReducer.js**

```
import { ADD_POST, GET_POSTS, POSTS_ERROR } from "../types";

const initialState = {
    posts: []
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload
            };
        case ADD_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload
            };
        case POSTS_ERROR:
            return {
                error: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default postReducer;
```

**posts.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../store/actions/postAction";

const Posts = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const postsList = useSelector((state) => state.postsList);
    const { loading, error, posts } = postsList;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <>
            {loading
                ? "Loading..."
                : error
                ? error.message
                : posts.map((post) => (
                      <div className="post" key={post.id}>
                          <h4>{post.title}</h4>
                          <p>{post.body}</p>
                      </div>
                  ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: You are mixing patterns in the same app, in `Posts` component you using react-hooks, and in `App` you use `connect` without actually passing the `addPost` there. Pass `mapDispatchToProps` to connect while fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please give me an example with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

App.js -> change to export default connect(null, {addPost})(App);

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does not solve the problem, there are other things that need to be added, but I am trying to understand what exactly is missing.